# Class With The Same Name Already Exists

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've created a class named "**Group**" in my .NET C# web-application.

When I try to access this class within other classes I get into no troubles, however, in certain points within my code when I try to access the very same class, it refers me to a different built-in class named "**Group**" too under the the lib. *Regular Expressions*.

**My question:** How can I specify directly that I am trying to access a different class? If there were 2 classes under different libs. named the same way, I would of just typed *X*.**Group** and *Y*.**Group** in order to specify the difference, but I'm not sure what I need to type in order to access my manually created class within my code.

**EDIT:** I have no namespace for my web-application as far as I know. I am using WebForms in order to develop my website, hence no namespace is created as far as I'm concerned.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Specify full name of your class - with all namespaces

Comment: @IVAAAN123 Read post edit please.

Comment: If you have no namespaces then you should create them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I specify directly that I am trying to access a different class

You could:

- Use the fully-qualified name, e.g.

  ```
  MyNamespace.Group x = new MyNamespace.Group();
  ```
- Avoid adding a `using` directive for `System.Text.RegularExpressions` unless you really need it (maybe fully-qualifying uses of that instead)
- Use an alias via a `using` directive:

  ```
  using MyGroup = MyNamespace.Group;
  ...
  MyGroup x = new MyGroup();
  ```

If you don't have a namespace declaration, you can just refer to `global::Group` instead of `MyNamespace.Group`... but I suspect you *do* have a namespace, and I'd urge you to create one if you don't already have one.

Comment: @TommyNaidich: I would be very surprised if you didn't have a namespace - and if you don't now, I'd strongly recommend that you *do*. Look in the codebehind to try to find a namespace declaration. There's an alternative I'll add to my answer though.

Comment: The "global::Group" method you have suggested works perfectly for me. To your second point - I have never had to create a namespace for my web applications and I can't see a real reason to do this in this particular project as well. Why not simply using "global::Group" whenever I need to access my class, instead of specifying a whole new namespace for my class and then changing every single code-line within my project to adjust to the change properly?

Answer will be accepted shortly by the way, thank you for your input.

Comment: @TommyNaidich: Why would you need to change "every single code line within your project"? That's *never* been my experience of using namespaces. Using namespaces is just a good idea in general, to allow for logical partitioning of names. I'd recommend at least trying it in your next project... I've never found it to be an issue at all.

Comment: Will do. Thank you once again, have a pleasant day.

Comment: If the rest of the world uses namespaces, it is fairly safe to use the global namespace as your personal namespace...

Comment: @Onots: That *really* doesn't scale though, does it? And it means that advice given for everyone else may not apply to the one person in the world who decides that they're "special". Bad idea, IMO.

Comment: Correct. It is a bad idea. Just like, "It is safe for you to not pay attention while driving if everyone else is paying attention." The latter part of that statement will always resolve to false.

Answer (score 2):

The first layer of protection against this problem is to be careful about giving your types such general names. That's the best solution.

Barring that, then you can do one of two things:

- Fully qualify the type name where you use it. E.g. `MyNamespace.Group`
- Declare a type alias via `using`. E.g. `using MySpecialGroup = MyNamespace.Group;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `using` directive:

```
using Group = X.Group;

var group = new Group(); \\ default Group class comes from X namespace;
var group2 = new Y.Group();  \\ if  you want other class, specify full namespace.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to access your own class in the code, you can create an alias for it with the `using` keyword:

```
using Group = My.Namespace.Group;
```

(at the top of your class, besides the normal using directives).

Otherwise it's always possible to use the fully qualified name in the code

```
var Group = new My.Namespace.Group;
```